# How do I access WhatsAppWeb in an Android WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, whatsapp

I want to use WhatsAppWeb (web.whatsapp.com) in an Android app. I've tried using a WebView and load the URL but I'm redirected to the regular WhatsApp page (www.whatsapp.com). I tried changing the User Agent

`mWebView.getSettings().SetUserAgentString("Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 78.0.3945.79 Safari / 537.36");`

but this only works if the app is started the first time. Each further start it redirects. Deleting Cache works (no redirect) but then I have to "authenticate" the device again.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using custom webview client? Please check this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/